# Switch from open jdk to Sun jdk

Tags: java

I have jdk1.7.0 directory in /usr/lib/jvm  along with other open-jdk versions. I want my Ubuntu 12.04 to treat this jdk(jdk1.7.0) as its primary jdk i.e. I dont want to use open-jdks.

When I type java -version or javac -version, both the times it returns that it is using openjdk and its jre. How can change it to jdk1.7.0?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put something similar to following to your `~/.bashrc`

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0"
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

for loading the changes, you can just run new bash by typing "bash" :]

Comment: Jiri it worked.Thanks. Can you tell what exactly the bash command does?

Comment: It opens a new bash (terminal if you want). If you make any changes to your `~/.bashrc`, these aren't taken into consideration immediately. You have to just open new bash. Another option would be to type `". ~/.bashrc"`

Comment: And to go from Sun JRE to OpenJRE? What would I set these variables to? thanks

Comment: @Geremia on my Fedora box I use following path `export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.60-2.4.3.0.fc19.i386"` but of course it depends

Answer (score 0):

Change the PATH variable so that `/usr/lib/jvm` is listed before the directory which contains Open JDK. If you are using bash, you can do this in the `.bashrc` file in your home directory.

Comment: I dont see any PATH variable in my .bashrc