# How to change open JDK to oracle JDK?

Tags: java, ubuntu-14.04

I have open jdk 1.7.0 and oracle jdk1.8.0. I already set JDK1.8.0's environment variables just follow https://askubuntu.com/questions/175514/how-to-set-java-home-for-java 
  But when I download open JDK1.7.0 and it is used automatically.When I type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

There was only one configuration : /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jr/bin/java and there was no need to configure it.

And I do like this [Switch from open jdk to Sun jdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13851621/switch-from-open-jdk-to-sun-jdk) It worked, but when i reboot my PC and it was no good.

How can i do?

Answer (score 2):

I got an answer:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_121/bin/java 1200
```

There are a new configuration choice in java link group when I type:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And now i can choose JDK1.8.0